# 3D Graph Network Topology Unknown search command fit

Tags: graph, visualization, splunk

I am new to splunk so I will try to be as clear as possible. I wanted to test the visualization of networkx graphs in Splunk 3D Graph Network Topology App. I was able to load the csv file of the graph successfully and I can see the data and the graph visualization. However, when I run community detection algorithm, it shows me the following error:

Unknown search command: 'fit'

Can somebody help me fix the issue please, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have the prerequisite apps installed, especially the Machine Learning Toolkit, which provides the `fit` command.  See https://splunkbase.splunk.com/app/4611/#/details.